# downloading pdf file without saving in Azure Functions python

Tags: python, pdf, azure-functions, pdfkit

I am generating a PDF file from HTML template using pdfkit library in Azure function using python.

Here is my code samples.

helper.py

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))

def give_me_pdf():
    filename = str(int(time.time()))
    template = env.get_template('index.html')
    html = template.render(name="David")
    pdfkit.from_file('html_report.html',filename+'.pdf')
    return filename
```

**init**.py

```
from helper import give_me_pdf

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    filename = give_me_pdf()
    downloadable = filename+'.pdf'
    with open(downloadable, 'rb') as f:
        mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(downloadable)
        return func.HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype=mimetype[0])
```

In the above code, a pdf is saved in my root folder when give_me_pdf function is called and then I am opening it in my azure function and returning it. How can I return the pdf file with out saving it in the root folder? Thanks

Comment: Sravan, did you find an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) states you can get back the PDF directly from the `from_file()` call if you omit the `output_path`:

> If you wish to further process generated PDF, you can read it to a variable:
>
> ```py
> # Without output_path, PDF is returned for assigning to a variable
> pdf = pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com')
> ```

So for your use, try this for `give_me_pdf()`:

```py
...
pdf_bytes = pdfkit.from_file('html_report.html')
return pdf_bytes
```

and then in `main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse`:

```py
...
pdf_bytes = give_me_pdf()
return func.HttpResponse(pdf_bytes, mimetype='application/pdf')  # use the well-defined MIME type for PDF
```